# Add custom headers with Volley library

Tags: android, android-volley

I start using Volley for my application and I want to add custom headers for each request as a security identifier.
I'm using a `JsonObjectRequest` and overriding the `getHeaders()`.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                        url,
                        null,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
                            }
                        }) {
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                        String mApiKey = "123";
                        headers.put("APIKEY", mApiKey);
                        return headers;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                        params.put("param1", "1");
                        params.put("param2", "2");
                        params.put("param3", "3");
                        return params;
                    }
                };
                VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

But I get this error:

```
E/Volley﹕ [23620] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for http://...
```

The `AuthFailureError` is thrown.

I also try to use `StringRequest` but same error.

If someone is in the same case and have solution, thank you in advance!

Comment: have you tested your request with a command line curl or the postman chrome plugin if it works? You do get a response, so is this a expected response? What is the API you are talking to expecting? have you tried to intercept your network traffic (mitm proxy) or log the traffic, so you can see if the header is set on the request?

Comment: @A.S. Yes I tried with Postman and it works. More when I try with DefaultHttpClient and HttpGet it works also. I will try to intercept my network traffic but I suspect that the header is not set.

Comment: @A.S. I can't install mitm proxy but I'm pretty sure that headers are not set with getHeaders()

Comment: You could try to force volley to log output => http://blog.zitec.com/2014/volley-an-android-http-library-from-google/  "Debugging and tracing"

Comment: Also try to set a `Log.i("Header", "requested headers")` in your `getHeaders()` overriden method, and check if it is ever called by the reuqest, for best result at the very last line before you return the headers

Comment: @A.S. Thank you, but I try to add my header in getParams() and now it works! I also have to not override getHeaders() even if it won't work. Don't understand why?

Comment: so you are adding the "APIKEY" to your params? Hmmm wired.... which kind of api is this?

Comment: Yes I add my APIKEY to params. It is an APIKEY relative to the user as an identifier (for security) and use for all request. It is also to prevent everyone to call my web services.

Comment: @A.S. I wrong sorry, the getParams() is never called with my GET request :( so my web service return empty data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add custom headers in volley request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054019/add-custom-headers-in-volley-request)

Answer (score 3):

This is a basic concept how to override a header in a standard VolleyRequest

```
VolleyRequest networkRequest = new VolleyRequest(request.getHttpMethod(), mUrlBase + request.getUrlSuffix(), responseListener, errorListener) {
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=" + getParamsEncoding();
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {               
             HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("X-Device-Info","Android FOO BAR");

            map.put("Accept-Language", acceptLanguage);
            map.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");         

            return map;             
        }

        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {

            try {
                String json = request.toJson().toString();
                if (json.length() < 3)
                    return ("{}").getBytes();
                // log(json);
                return json.getBytes(getParamsEncoding());
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "getBody(): request has no json");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return new byte[0];
        }
    };
```

Comment: Alex, I'm having the same problem. Did you ever get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomJsonObjectRequest  extends JsonObjectRequest
{
    public CustomJsonObjectRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,Response.Listener listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener)
    {
        super(method, url, jsonRequest, listener, errorListener);
    }


@Override
public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map headers = new HashMap();
    headers.put(Constants.accesstoken, Globals.getInstance().getAccessToken());
    Logger.debugE(Constants.accesstoken, headers.toString());
    return headers;
    }

}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.