# Volley java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to convert my app to use WebAPI and token authenication. I'm also moving away from Apache http and using volley.

Below i have a class called NetworkManager that handles the volley requests.
In my main Activity there is a login button that calls a method getAuthenicationTokens from the networkManager class. I have used a customeListener to relay the response back to the calling Activity.

CustomListener:

```
public interface CustomListener<T>
{
    public void getResult(T object);
}
```

.

Activity:

```
buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {



                NetworkManager.getInstance().getAuthenticationTokens(null, new CustomListener<JSONObject>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void getResult(JSONObject result)
                    {

                        Log.e(TAG, "Json object length = " + result.length());

                    }
                });
```

.

Method in NetworkManager:

```
public void getAuthenticationTokens(Object param1, final CustomListener<JSONObject> listener)
    {

        //String url = prefixURL + "this/request/suffix";
        String url = "https://lw.xxx.co.uk/connect/token";

        Map<String, Object> jsonParams = new HashMap<>();


        jsonParams.put("scope", "openid email phone profile offline_access roles");
        jsonParams.put("resource", "window.location.origin");
        jsonParams.put("grant_type", "password");
        jsonParams.put("username", "support@xxx.com");
        jsonParams.put("password", "tempPxxx");

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new JSONObject(jsonParams),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG + ": ", "somePostRequest Response : " + response.toString());
                        if(null != response.toString())
                            listener.getResult(response);
                    }
                },

                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                    {
                        if (null != error.networkResponse)
                        {
                            Log.d(TAG + ": ", "Error Response code: " + error.networkResponse.statusCode);
                            listener.getResult(null);
                        }
                    }
                }){
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String,String> params =  super.getHeaders();
                        if(params==null)params = new HashMap<>();
                        params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                        //..add other headers
                        return params;
                    }
        };



        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
```

.

I have tried to add a header to the request using the following post(answer by Subhash), but i'm getting the following exception from adding the headers.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054019/add-custom-headers-in-volley-request)

Exception:

```
NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
                                                                            java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
                                                                                       at java.util.AbstractMap.put(AbstractMap.java:203)
                                                                                       at loneworker.carefreegroup.com.loneworker.NetworkManager$3.getHeaders(NetworkManager.java:100)
                                                                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:93)
                                                                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
                                                                                       at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
```

.

Has anyone any ideas what what the problem is with adding the headers.
The exception is on line 100, here

```
params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: The error seems to say you cannot modify super.getHeaders(), try to copy that in some new HashMap then add.

Comment: @RC. Hi I have tried just Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                        params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");    But it still doesn't work. Is that how you meant to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>(super.getHeaders());
```

I tested it and it worked for me.