# How to put header in url using volley in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-volley, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension, rx-kotlin

My code-

```
val accessTokenRequest: JsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            Response.Listener { response ->
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                Toast.makeText(activity,error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
    )

    AppController.instance!!.addToRequestQueue(accessTokenRequest)
```

Header I wat to put -
"Search"&
"Authorization"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add custom headers in volley request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054019/add-custom-headers-in-volley-request)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the following code to add headers

```
val accessTokenRequest: JsonObjectRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(
    Request.Method.GET, "", JSONObject(),
    Response.Listener<JSONObject?> {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }, Response.ErrorListener {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}) {
    @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
    override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
        var params: MutableMap<String, String>? = super.getHeaders()
        if (params == null) params = HashMap()
        params["Authorization"] = "Your authorization"
        //..add other headers
        return params
    }
}
```

**Note: To generate kotlin code from java try using Ctrl + Shift + Alt + K or simply copy paste it on a kotlin file.**

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made my day.

Comment: That code results in an error UnsupportedOperationException at java.util.AbstractMap.put. remove the first 2 lines in getHeaders() and just instsantiate a new map right away val params: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()

Answer (score 0):

As @chitgoks said @Abilash code occurs `UnsupportedOperationException at java.util.AbstractMap.put` error. So I rewrote his code to fix it.

```kotlin
val accessTokenRequest: JsonObjectRequest = object :
            JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "", JSONObject(), Response.Listener<JSONObject?> {
                // Add something you want to run on success
            }, Response.ErrorListener {
                // Add something you wanna run on error
            }) {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                params.putAll(super.getHeaders())
                params["Accept"] = "application/json"
                //add your header like above line
                return params
            }
        }
```